# In Eclipse, can one rename Java packages without causing a name conflict between 'test' and 'main'?

Tags: eclipse, m2e

In an Eclipse project using the standard Maven layout, renaming a package in the `test` source branch fails with a name conflict, if the package exists in `main`.

*Can Eclipse perform such a refactoring?* Thank you.

The installed versions are:

1. Eclipse Juno, Build id: 20120614-1722
2. m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.1.0.20120530-0009
   org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group Eclipse.org
3. Maven Integration for WTP 0.15.2.20120306-2040
   org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with maven.  Within a single java project you can not have two packages with the same name, even if those packages are in different source folders.